# Why does the mysql client get "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock'" when connecting to REMOTE server?

Tags: php, mysql, bash, shell, cron

I have two systems, a web server and a mysql server. The web server is having the issue where its mysql client fails on connecting a **REMOTE** mysql server with a shell script, triggered by a cron job. The cron job uses the root user, and I am able to login as root and run the script on the command line with no problems.

The shell script `optimizestatements.sh` has:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql --login-path=remoteserver -se "OPTIMIZESTATEMENT"`;
```

Using `mysql_config_editor`, I have set up an encrypted options file to avoid sending the login password in the clear. When I created that option file, I used the direct IP address of the remote server.

The cron job entry is simple:

```
HOME=/
TERM=dumb
0 1 * * * /usr/local/bin/optimizestatements.sh | ts '[\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S]' >> /var/log/cron_optimizedb 2>&1
```

In my previous searches for an answer, almost all of them say that the local mysql isn't running on the web server, but they don't necessarily apply to my case because I am not connecting to my local mysql service to optimize it, I am attempting to connect to the remote mysql server.

I don't want mysql running on my web server. I just want to use the installed mysql client.

Furthermore, as I already pointed out, running the command on the command line as the same user as cron has no problems whatsoever and doesn't have the local socket issue.

Is there something else I'm missing in the process? Why does the cron job need the local mysql daemon running, but running it manually on the command line doesn't?

Comment: Does a  `.mylogin.cnf`  exist in `$HOME` of the cron user, root in your case? Maybe cron isn't setting `$HOME` so the `mysql` cannot find it. Couldn't you just use the [MySQL event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) system to put your optimize statements?

Comment: Yes there's a .mylogin.cnf in the correct user's home directory, but now that you mention it, in the crontab I have HOME set to / and that is likely messing up how the script is running. I will also look into the MySQL event system, I didn't even think to do that. Thank you.